# want to find a suitable data structure for this question?

Tags: algorithm

A new piece of hardware is now available to the general public, they are called Fast Hard Drives (FHD). Unlike traditional Hard Drives, FHDs do not have any mechanical parts. Similar  to  a  RAM  memory,  FHDs  allow  random  access:  any  memory  address  can  be accessed in constant time by simply using a pointer to that address. However, they also allow much larger storage space.

The University of Hackertown is another university who wants to employ FHDs for their database and they have similar requirements to Prudentville. However, they developed an internal, proprietary method that allows parallel access to contiguous records in a FHD using a single reading operation. They also enhanced their FHDs with a RAM cache that stores the result of this parallel operation and allow 100x faster search if the record is in this cache. Which data structure would you use in this case? Remember to explain your reasoning.
I am a bit confused about the question. I think it is B-tree but do not know how to explain it.

Comment: "Use" for what? For the cache? For the file system? For the allocations? For some application running on this hardware?

Answer (score 0):

From my rudimentary understanding, B-trees are a suitable data structure in this case because unlike binary trees, B-tree nodes store multiple keys per node and each node can have multiple children. As a result, B-trees have relatively shorter heights. B-trees are self-balancing which allows them to maintain `O(log n)` for all operations (look ups, insertions, and deletions). The shallow structure allows for more efficient look ups, even when the data set is very large since you don't have to traverse as many nodes.